# Best way to generate a unique link for a user and save data to that links user nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building an application form that has a reference requirement. Once a user applies, an email is sent to the reference their have entered and that reference is supposed to fill in a form whose information should be saved under the applicant.

So how do I generate a unique link for a user and have input from that link saved to the Mongo collection of the user?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I want to generate a unique link I usually follow the process:

1 - I setup a specific field to hold the value in the database table/collection: lets say `Users.formId` if the user should only have one unique url at a time. It depends on your requirements.

2 - I setup a route to resolve that url:

```
app.get("/form/:id", async (req, res) => {
   // other code
   const document = await User.findOne({ formId: req.params.formId });
   // other code
})
```

3 - I setup a POST route that should trigger the creation of the unique `formId`. The route handler should leverage a library such as [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate a new unique value, save it in the database, and send an email to the user with the following combination `https://YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/FRONTEND-ROUTE/3c53a7bb-7fec-4197-98d4-ff97bf744aa6`.

3 - Then your frontend should have a route that retrieves the id in the URL and send a POST request to the endpoint you created in the step 2.